# Beamer - Reference slide is shown in incorrect style

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm using the followjng code to create a Reference-slide in my Beamer-presentation:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{References}
         \cite{Feng2014}
         \bibliography{myReferences}
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I have created a myReferences.bib file using JabRef and simply including the following in the BibTeX-Section: [Google Scholar](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:rPy0lMjpNWwJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAXMsR6iTt2BcocmVnB3dLIs8w6hW_e3jI&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en)

I do get a Reference slide, but I don't want the weird part in the big brackets to be there. Instead I want numbers, as should be guaranteed by using ieetr-style:
[image: my references]

Does anyone know why this is happenning?
Here is the .bbl:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Feng et~al., 2014]{Feng2014}
Feng, B., Fu, M., Ma, H., Xia, Y., and Wang, B. (2014).
\newblock Kalman filter with recursive covariance estimation - sequentially
  estimating process noise covariance.
\newblock {\em IEEE transactions on Industrial Electronics}, 61(11):6253--6263.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: One thing that jumps to my eye is that you are nesting `frame`s: ` \begin{frame}{References}
        \begin{frame}{References}`. If undoing this does not solve the issue, you may want to provide a complete example, i.e. add the relevant part of the bib file.

Comment: whops, my mistake. Actually this was just a typo here, I don't have nested frames in my original .tex ... I have included the .bbl in my post now. This has been generated by JabRef